How would shopkeepers deal with a nine percent tax?
We imagine a world with D&D currency (1 gold (gp) = 10 silver (sp) = 100 copper (cp)). And a city where all transactions attract a 9% sales tax which goes to the government. So if a thing costs 1gp, you actually pay 1gp+9cp. The tax is this value for occult reasons which aren’t important here, and it being a very awkward amount is not a reason to change it. The tax also always rounds up (so if a thing costs 10cp and therefore would cost 10.9cp with the tax, you pay 11cp.)
How would shopkeepers behave in this city? How would they price things? For example, a thing costing 11cp would, with tax, cost 12cp almost exactly; on the other hand, a thing costing 1cp would cost 2cp (because the tax always rounds up). Would this incline shopkeepers to generally make prices some value where the tax is as close to a fair while copper as possible? (So a shopkeeper would be inclined to price a thing at 11cp rather than 10cp or 12cp, and so prices will gravitate towards multiples of 11.) Or would they be indifferent to the tax (they don’t get the “extra” that may come from rounding; the government get it) and just price things how they would normally?
How would these shopkeepers work out the tax? Would a shopkeeper price a thing at 60cp and work out the tax (should be 5.4cp, therefore 6cp) when they label an item, or work it out when someone pays? What convenient mental mathematical tricks might they work out to quickly calculate the 9% tax (something like the mental mathematical tricks for quickly dividing a number by 7, multiplying by 11, and so on)?

What's likely to happen is that instead of 10, 1 silver coin is equal to 12 coppers (as it used to be in England). Most transactions will be done in silver, and for each sp the shopkeeper receives, he'll hold out 1 cp for the government. Simple and close enough to still be observing the sacred 9%.

Shopkeepers will try to minimize the tax that their customers pay, because if they don't, a competitor will and thus take their customers. As part of that, inexpensive items will start being sold in multiples, to avoid the 1cp + 9% = 2cp problem. In any case, shopkeepers will avoid losing money if they can possibly can, and will be quite creative about finding ways to do that.
If 1cp is a significant amount, shopkeepers will petition the government to introduce smaller coins. If the government refuses to do that, some enterprising smith may introduce a system of tokens "which are not money" but which can be bought and sold "as collectables" or some similar excuse, to take the place of smaller coins. Alternatively, people may cut up the coins to make small change, although a government might make that illegal.
If the 9% tax stays stable for many years, special coins may start being minted, worth 9% of regular coins.

People will physically cut the coins to make subdivisions. This is what "pieces of eight" you see in pirate movies refers to: the practice of cutting the Spanish dollar into 8 pieces.

Worth adding but probably not worth another answer - the shopkeeper setting prices is obviously going to figure out how much needs to go to his pocket. At the same time he can't be indifferent to the tax, because if he doesn't minimize the tax, someone else will adjust the quantities to sell the same good cheaper and take his business. This is all just Economics 101.

@user111403: thanks, added.

@user71659 not likely. That happens when the value of the coin is roughly equal to the metal in the coin, and the coin is too valuable for many transactions. That doesn't seem to be the case here. It won't help with the tax because the government will almost certainly insist on tax being paid in whole coins.

@user111403 Nope, the value of the coin doesn't matter. Modern coins are mostly worth less than the metal (and all notes are), yet we assign a monetary value to them. Society accepts that an 11.1 cent disk of metal is worth 1/4 of a US dollar. What prevents society, when needed, from accepting that 1/2 that disk is worth 1/8 a dollar?

@user71659 seriously, of course I know that. But when you need 5 dollars, do you take a 10 dollar bill and rip it in half, or do you ask for change? Fiat money is still backed by something - historically, a promise to exchange it for a commodity (gold in the US), more recently by a government declaring it legal tender. If the metal isn't valuable, after cutting the coin has neither intrinsic nor fiat value. Sure, society could accept have the disk, but it won't, or only at a steep discount. One whole coin will always be preferred to two halves.

It could still happen, of course, if there are many transactions with a value less than the smallest coin. But that's not likely if copper is abundant and it's tangential to the question. It doesn't help with taxes unless the government is willing to accept partial coins, and they have no reason to, since rounding is in their favor (apart from the headache of counting and weighing them).

@user111403 Once the transactions are digitized, things can be sold with values less than the smallest coin. For example, many financial transactions in the US record 1/10th or 1/100th cent values so that interest payments can be calculated on a daily basis.

@user111403 Again, you make no sense. As long as shopkeepers, customers, and suppliers are willing to flexibly trade two halves for one whole, the system works. You're way overthinking it. You rip currency in half when there's no alternative. This is like the US military store system (AAFES/BX) giving paper pogs instead of coins when deployed overseas: they have no choice and their community accepts it as equivalent.

@user71659 I'm trying to spell it out as much as I can in 600 chars, sorry if it's not clear. Yes, as long as everyone is willing to exchange two halves for a whole, the system works. But that "as long as" is a big assumption that you have to justify. Why would everyone be willing to trade? If the government accepts half coins, then sure. But if it doesn't, half coins are limited. They can't be used to pay taxes and you can't force a creditor to accept them in payment of a debt. That means that by default they're worth less than the whole.

@user111403 (Sane) people don't pay taxes or major debts, their mortgage or buy a car with coins, or even dollar bills, and rounding has little effect there anyway. Real example: the US IRS allows rounding to whole dollar amounts on every single line when doing your taxes, so even if you paid in cash, you'll never need coins. So you could make the argument that coins are devalued today.

And again, this is still all tangential to the original question unless the government agrees to accept taxes of half a coin, which it has no reason to do since rounding is always in its favor. @DavidR that also applies to digital transactions, there will be reasons to track fractions of a coin but it won't be relevant to sales tax unless the government decides it is.

@user71659 yes, coins are somewhat devalued. In theory, 100 pennies are equal in worth to a dollar, but good luck paying your restaurant bill in pennies.

@user111403 But people regularly pay a portion of their restaurant bill in pennies which is accepted at face value. So no devaluation occurs in reasonable normal use. Therefore what you are claiming does not make sense.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.


I understand that in America displayed prices do not include applicable taxes, so that you never know how much you will pay for an item. In Europe, the law requires that the displayed prices represent what the customer has to pay, including VAT, excise tax, everything.
For Americans, value-added tax (VAT) is sort of like a sales tax, except that the shopkeeper is allowed to claim back the amount of tax that they paid to their suppliers. And in Europe it is around 20%.
You make your choice whether this is an American city or an European city.

As for how the sales personnel compute it, the answer is, they don't; they have tables with the tax pre-computed and they read the value from the table.



RE: the footnote, in the US, items purchased for resale are sales-tax exempt.

@user71659: Yes, that is the great difference between a US-style sales tax and a European-style value-added tax. In America, no sales tax applies throughout the chain manufacturer to distributor to retail seller; in Europe, each step of the chain pays VAT on the difference between the cost they paid and the price they charged. That is why it is called a tax on value added.

@AlexP It is not in America, it is in individual states. There is no sales tax in Alaska, Delaware, Montana, New Hampshire, and Oregon.

In Economics, this is called a Game Theory problem
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Game_theory
Game theory is the idea that in a system of multiple competing entities, each entity will attempt to choose the strategy that best serves it taking into consideration what the competing entities are choosing to do.  So, how a merchant marks thier prices will not be standardized.
In an unrounded tax system, you may see an item worth 12, 13, or 14cp.  But your tax system basically means that the store owner does not make any extra money by selling something for 13cp so he has to decide based on market trends if his customers will pay the extra cp of taxes at 14cp so that he can make 1 more cp or if his volume of sales can give him a better profit at 12cp.  The answer to this is not set in stone, but has to do with his customer's and competitors choices.  If he sets the price of an item at 14cp and the guy across the street from him also hicks the price up to 14cp, then they will likely both make a bigger profit than if they both set it to 12cp, but if one sets to 14cp and the other to 12cp, then this could make a bigger difference than before when maybe one sold for 13cp and the other for 12cp; so, in this case, the guy who was charging 13cp may be forced to drop his price to 12cp.  Then there is each vendor's ability to leverage other factors.  If you are the more convenient, more trusted, or more well known vendor, you might still be able to make the best possible profit selling at 14cp even if the guy across the street is selling the same thing at 12cp.  Then there are cultural norms that might develop around this.  A nationalist society might actually see 13cp as the most patriotic price to charge because you are showing you care enough about your community to collect the extra tax but not so much about yourself to ask for the next cp of profit after that; so, 13cp would be a commonly encouraged price.  In another society, asking for 13 cp might be seen as foolish making people not trust you.  One society might find 14cp to be common and okay whereas in another 14cp is always seen as greedy making most things cost either 12 or 15cp... that's right, it could be easier to sell a 15cp item than a 14cp simply because people find prices of 1 over tax distasteful.
In short, it is too complicated for any one answer to always be applicable; so, for simplicity sake, I would not overthink it too much.  Unless the players actually go out of thier way to find a store with a certain set of values.
How to Gamify Game Theory
Alternatively, this is DnD; so, you could just roll for it.  We know that most vendors will round up or down by 1 on any item that is normally listed somewhere in the middle; so, you could just roll a d20.  On a 11-20, round down. On a 10, that vendor does not know his tax code and he charges the normal rate anyway. On 2-9 the vendor rounds up and on a 1 he rounds up by 2... or something like that.
How would shopkeepers know how much to charge?
There were no Walmart Supercenters back then.  Each vendor sells a limited number of items; so, they are not doing mental math to calculate tax rates because they are selling few enough items to simply memorize the final cost of everything they sell.
